# Pythonnet cann't load System.IO.Path (.net 6.0)

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I use Python 3.10 and Net 6.0. And my C# code call Directory.GetFiles function from System.IO.

When I call dll from python using Pythonnet, it showed cannot load type: System.IO.Path.

Please provide some instructions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
from clr_loader import get_coreclr
from pythonnet import set_runtime
rt = get_coreclr(runtime_config = r"D:\runtimeConfig.json")
set_runtime(rt)
```

and json file:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "6.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```